# How to set up foreign key in Entity Framework with data annotations?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am trying to build a web application that connects to a SQL Server using Entity Framework. I have three classes, one is to register consultations, the second one is for registering contact information and the last one is to classify consultations types (kind of like an enumerable but I need to store more data).

Every consultation has a contact information (so there is a reference to the primary key of table `Contact`) and a `ConsultationType` (another reference to the primary key of table `Type`).

```
public class Consultation
{
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }

    public long ContactID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactID")]
    public Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public long ConsultationTypeID{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ConsultationTypeID")]
    public ConsultationType Type { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class ConsultationType
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string type{ get; set; }
    public string abbreviated{ get; set; }
}
```

The `Consultation` table has 3 columns (`id`, `ContactID` and `ConsultationTypeID`). I am expecting all the `Contact` and `ConsultationType` references to be filled automatically based on the ID in the foreign keys.

Currently when I retrieve data from the database, only the `ConsultationType` gets filled, not the contact. I can not understand this behaviour because I think I have all set up the same way.

**EDIT**: when I retrieve `Consultation` data, I get a list of objects with 5 properties (consultation ID, contact ID, contact, consultation type Id, consultation type). 4 of them are set (only contact is not set). I want the contact property to be set to an instance of the row that contains the ID referenced by the Contact ID property.

Comment: Please try to read again what you have written. What do you meand by Contact and Consultation Type to be filled automatically. There must be data in Contact and Consultation type to create a Consultation not the opposite. Sorry if i understood it wrong

Comment: Can you show your Select method? Did you add include?

Comment: When I retrieve Consultation data, I get a list of objects with 5 properties (consultation ID, contact ID, contact, consultation type Id, consultation type). 4 of them are set (only contact is not set). I want the contact property to be set to an instance of the row that contains the ID rerenced by the Contact ID property.

Comment: For the select method, I have a DbContext and I only use this function 
`Consultation = await _context.Consultations.ToListAsync();`

Answer (score 0):

Rereading the select part.

```
consultationTypes = await _context.ConsultationTypes.ToListAsync();
Consultation = await _context.Consultations.ToListAsync();
```

I thought that maybe I should load the Contact also. So I have added:

```
await _context.ConsultationTypes.ToListAsync();
await _context.Contacts.ToListAsync();
Consultation = await _context.Consultations.ToListAsync();
```

I don't really understand why I need to do it, but it is working now. I wonder if there is a way to load all tables so I don't have to do it every time.